# Can't embed my own notes (in a page that I own)

Tags: facebook, embed, posts

I got a professional page for my work with some public notes on it.
I see the "Embed post" button and my notes are public, but when I try to embed the post, that doesn't works.

Error message : This Facebook post is no longer available. It may have been removed or the privacy settings of the post may have changed.

Anyone has an idea ?

Link for example : https://www.facebook.com/notes/f2000fr/r%C3%A9seaux-sociaux-entre-identit%C3%A9-sociale-et-vie-priv%C3%A9e/703262716434347

Thanks !

Comment: That is a note and not a post.

Comment: I think the confusion here is that even though it is a note, there is a box to the right of the note (on facebook) which says "embed post".  When you click on it, it gives embed code _for this note_. So, the confusion is understandable.  WizKid, if you'd like to help, please explain why/that notes are not embeddable or something more descriptive about the problem.